# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time in azure notification hub

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-notificationhub

full internal exeption which i got is : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
i am getting this error in azure notification hub. some time code run smoothly but sometime gives this error for following operation

await hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation);
await hub.PatchInstallationAsync(Id, updates);

here hub=NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("**","**")

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication of internal server problems, or extremely high latencies. Could you open a support request in the Azure Portal so the team can take a look at your particular namespace and see what's going on? Thanks.